# Mongodb Query to get the nth document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to create a query in mongodb that needs to return the SECOND TO THE LAST document. I am planning to use $group for this query but i dont know what aggregation function to use. I only know $first and $last.

I have an example collection below and also include the expected output. Thank you!

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b4"),
    "auditlogs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84be"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe702d59a9205db81fcb69"),
            "action" : "ADDTRANSACTION"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84bd"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe644f9493e05db9245192"),
            "action" : "EDITPROFILE"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84bc"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe64949493e05db9245197"),
            "action" : "DELETETRANSACTION"
        } ]


 "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b75ge2"),
    "auditlogs" : [ 

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84bb"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe64b69493e05db924519b"),
            "action" : "ADDTRANSACTION"
   
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84ba"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe65419493e05db92451d4"),
            "action" : "ADDTRANSACTION"

        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b9"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe65689493e05db92451d9"),
            "action" : "CHANGEACCESS"

        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b8"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe65819493e05db92451dd"),
            "action" : "DELETETRANSACTION"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b7"),
            "userid" : ObjectId("5ffe65df9493e05db92451f3"),
            "action" : "EDITPROFILE",
 ]
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b4"),"_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84bd"),"userid" : ObjectId("5ffe644f9493e05db9245192"),"action" : "EDITPROFILE"},
 {"_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b75ge2"),"_id" : ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b8"),"userid" : ObjectId("5ffe65819493e05db92451dd"),"action" : "DELETETRANSACTION"}
```

Comment: Re-write the question if you can with simple ids like numbers.If you want what i think you want,a simple solution for small collections would be to sort and then group, keeping all data in an array and then take the last 2 after the group  with `$slice`.For bigger collections i dont know if there  is a way to do it with MongoDB operators,but you can always use a custom js accumulator [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/).(sort and group with custom js accumulator that has for example 1 array with 2 places,and there you keep only the max 2 or min 2)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two `_id` keys in one single object.

I've made the parent object's id to `_parentId` you can give it's a name anything you want except `_id`

Aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$auditlogs"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_parentId": "$_id", 
      "_id": "$auditlogs._id",
      "action": "$auditlogs.action",
      "userid": "$auditlogs.userid",
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xHsaDwMSYL9)

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the array by -2 to get the last two item, then by 1 to get first one. Therefore, the array will be left the second to the last. Finally, unwind auditlogs so it can be changed from array to object which is structure that you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: { auditlogs : { $slice: [ "$auditlogs", -2 ] } } 
    },
    { 
        $project: { auditlogs : { $slice: [ "$auditlogs", 1 ] } } 
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$auditlogs"
    }
])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.